# Explicitly Validating Certificates

Tags: security-certificate, http

I am unable to make any API calls to the API I'd like to because the certificate is invalid. How do I go about adding the certificate to a trusted group so that it is automatically trusted? As it stands all I get is Insecure Request Warnings and 404 responses from any requests.

Comment: What tools are you using to make calls to the API?   Different tools will have different instructions.  For example for `curl` see: [How to trust self-signed certificate in cURL command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451207/how-to-trust-self-signed-certificate-in-curl-command-line)

Comment: Your question is too vague, you do not give any detail. How do you query things? Why is the certificate invalid? (wrong dates, self signed, signed by unknown CA, etc.). Etc. You need to provide all of that when you ask for help, typically: what I want to do, how I try to do it (which commands I send, etc...) what results do I get (as text, not as an image, and directly the output not a rephrasing of it) and what I expected instead. Also, your question may be off topic here because as it stands it does not seem really to be about running a website. Please read help section to double check.